# Pandas: subtracting 2 specific rows on a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, difference, subtraction

I have a dataframe that look like this:

```
WW XX YY ZZ
a  10 20 30
b  4  5  6
c  7  8  9
```

I would like to subtract row `c` from row `a`, and add a new row `d` at the end to display the result

The expected result should look like this:

```
WW XX YY ZZ
a  10 20 30
b  4  5  6
c  7  8  9 
d  3  12 21
```

I've tried transposing the dataframe and use the `df['a'] - df['c']` method, but figure there should be a better way.

Comment: Does the dataframe have an index?

Comment: It doesn't, although I can make the first column 'WW' an index if needed since it has unique values.

Answer (score 3):

assuming WW is the index (if not use: df.set_index("WW")), try:

```
df.loc['d'] = df.loc['a'] - df.loc['c']
```

Comment: And can then reset_index if required.